# 3D Object Joints Accessing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator, iphone-developer-program

I have 3D object in Maya which have joints for its movements, how can I access the object's joints in iPhone, Kindly guide me so that I can make it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no iPhone API for this. You'll have to find a game engine that runs on iPhone and integrates with Maya.

Unity and SIO2 both run on iPhone and cite Maya support, and there are probably others. Whether said support includes inverse joint data, I don't know.

Actually, try asking on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. I only just found out about it.